# I was unable to download node module through terminal

Tags: node.js

Command to download node modules module npm i
Error: npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\nas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@14.18.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.8/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.8-node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.8/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.8-node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.8/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.8-node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.8 and node@14.18.1 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.8/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.8-node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.18.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.18.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\nas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:330:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\nas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:159:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Users\nas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:228:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\nas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:294:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:390:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:402:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:280:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\nas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\nas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\fieldforce\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nas\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-01T07_39_35_752Z-debug-0.log

Comment: According to the log, your npm is not able to locate your paython environment in your PATH `ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python`

Comment: @RomanHDev then how to install python envionment?

Comment: If you don't have one installed already, yes. Also judging from your error log, I'd assume you are running Windows. So when running the installer make sure you tick the 'add to PATH' checkbox. Adding python to the system PATH under windows after the fact can be a pain

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the bcryptjs from package. Then give "npm i" command after this install bcrypt separately